# Как получить id пользователя для отправки фото в директорию?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет!
Никак не получается сделать так, чтобы определенное изображение/файл отправлялся в директорию 'images/id-пользователя либо его username/'

```
 first_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/'+ str(usern.get_username()) + '/', null=True, max_length=255)
```

Делаю так, но получаю просто "%имя класса.метод()%"

Каким методом можно решить это?

Comment: Как эта модель связана с моделью `User`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю вам следущее решение на основе ответов с сети и официальной документации

```
def get_user_dir_path(instance, filename):
    return 'images/%d/%s' % (instance.user.id, filename)
    # или вариант ниже
    # return 'images/%s/%s' % (instance.user.username, filename) 

# Поле в вашей модели
first_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_user_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
```

[Дока upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

[Ответ на стороннем ресурсе](https://toster.ru/q/67640)